# How to fire same event when click on nested element

Tags: javascript, events

I have a div inside another div. When I am clicking on inner div I am getting that inner div as target. And when I am clicking on outer div I am getting that outer div as target. So how I get inner div by clicking on inner and outer div (both) without assign different events to both divs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: on a fetched click event on an element, in the target object is the element under the mouse. So you can't have the same routine for both elements, unless you handle both differently in one

Comment: no @tevemadar. But thanks for this useful answer.